# Remove ELPA files from the recentf list

Tags: recentf

I recently started using `recentf-mode`. However, during a package refresh (using `auto-package-update`) my recentf list gets cluttered with all the package autoloads file:

```
/home/polesz/.emacs.d/elpa/yasnippet-20170808.940/yasnippet-autoloads.el
/home/polesz/.emacs.d/elpa/async-20170804.2158/async-autoloads.el
/home/polesz/.emacs.d/elpa/dash-20170810.137/dash-autoloads.el
/home/polesz/.emacs.d/elpa/with-editor-20170803.917/with-editor-autoloads.el
/home/polesz/.emacs.d/elpa/web-mode-20170807.903/web-mode-autoloads.el
/home/polesz/.emacs.d/elpa/typescript-mode-20170813.1541/typescript-mode-autoloads.el
/home/polesz/.emacs.d/elpa/markdown-mode-20170812.1201/markdown-mode-autoloads.el
/home/polesz/.emacs.d/elpa/rich-minority-20170813.622/rich-minority-autoloads.el
/home/polesz/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20170814/org-loaddefs.el
/home/polesz/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20170814/org-autoloads.el
/home/polesz/.emacs.d/elpa/secretaria-20170813.1107/secretaria-autoloads.el
/home/polesz/.emacs.d/elpa/helm-core-20170810.2231/helm-core-autoloads.el
/home/polesz/.emacs.d/elpa/helm-20170813.1420/helm-autoloads.el
/home/polesz/.emacs.d/elpa/multiple-cursors-20170813.38/multiple-cursors-autoloads.el
/home/polesz/.emacs.d/elpa/pdf-tools-20170813.731/pdf-tools-autoloads.el
/home/polesz/.emacs.d/elpa/helm-bibtex-20170808.1124/helm-bibtex-autoloads.el
/home/polesz/.emacs.d/elpa/ivy-20170813.351/ivy-autoloads.el
/home/polesz/.emacs.d/elpa/hydra-20170813.1058/hydra-autoloads.el
/home/polesz/.emacs.d/elpa/org-ref-20170808.625/org-ref-autoloads.el
/home/polesz/.emacs.d/elpa/org-category-capture-20170731.2235/org-category-capture-autoloads.el
```

Is there a way to disable recentf saving while package update is ongoing? If not, is there a way to remove a specific directory (`/home/polesz/.emacs.d/elpa` in my case) from the recentf list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

on my side, I just ignored elpa folder by adding that:

```
(add-to-list 'recentf-exclude (format "%s/\\.emacs\\.d/elpa/.*" (getenv "HOME")))
```

Comment: This `recentf-exclude` variable is new to me, that's exactly what I was looking for.